# Fairly simple XSD generating ObjectFactory wrapping root element class in JAXBElement

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I'm struggling to understand why XJC is generating an `ObjectFactory` that wraps instances of the class corresponding to the root element in a `JAXBElement` wrapper.

The root element does not use an anonymous complex type.  (You have to be a little careful when reviewing this schema because there are pairs of complexType names that at first glance look the same, but one is plural and the other  singular -- e.g. `optionalParametersType` and `optionalParameterType`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
           xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="urn:com-mbm-parameters"
           targetNamespace="urn:com-mbm-parameters"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           jaxb:version="2.0">
  <xs:element name="parameters" type="parametersType" />

  <xs:complexType name="parametersType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="option-parameters"              type="optionParametersType"             minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="positional-parameters"          type="positionalParametersType"         minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="mutually-exclusive-parameters"  type="mutuallyExclusiveParametersType"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="properties-file" type="xs:string" use="optional"/> 
  </xs:complexType>
  <!--

  -->
  <xs:complexType name="optionParametersType">
   <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="option-parameter" type="optionParameterType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <!--

  -->
  <xs:complexType name="optionParameterType">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="description" type="descriptionType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="command-line-name" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="default-value" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <!--

  -->
  <xs:complexType name="positionalParametersType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="positional-parameter" type="positionalParameterType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <!--

  -->
  <xs:complexType name="positionalParameterType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="description" type="descriptionType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <!--

  -->
  <xs:complexType name="descriptionType">
     <xs:attribute name="forValue" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <!--

  -->
  <xs:complexType name="mutuallyExclusiveParametersType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="mutually-exclusive-parameter-set" type="mutuallyExclusiveParameterSetType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <!--

  -->
  <xs:complexType name="mutuallyExclusiveParameterSetType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="mutually-exclusive-parameter" type="mutuallyExclusiveParameterType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <!--

  -->
  <xs:complexType name="mutuallyExclusiveParameterType">
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Here's the snippet of `ObjectFactory` that returns instances of the `ParametersType` class:

```
/**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link ParametersType }{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "urn:com-mbm-parameters", name = "parameters")
    public JAXBElement<ParametersType> createParameters(ParametersType value) {
        return new JAXBElement<ParametersType>(_Parameters_QNAME, ParametersType.class, null, value);
    }
```

This is the *only* place the `JAXBElement` is used within the entire `ObjectFactory,` so it's not there to disambiguate two or more possible elements.

Any idea why this is happening and how to remove the need to use the wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `JAXBElement` for top-level elements, which, in this case, is your `parameters` element.

The rationale is to separate types and elements (which you can see as instances of types). So it is, actually, to disambiguate two or more possible elements - you may have *another* schema which has a different element of the same `parametersType`. Global elements are sometimes references via `<xs:element ref="..."/>`, they can have substitution groups etc., so in general always have `JAXBElement`s for global elements is not completely unreasonable. I'm not saying it is the best design decision, I'm just saying there is some rationale in it.

To get rid of the wrapper, try using `xjc:simple` or adding `@XmlRootElement` annotation on your own:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39778670/303810
- [JAXB xjc:simple binding does not generate @XmlRootElement for base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879392/jaxb-xjcsimple-binding-does-not-generate-xmlrootelement-for-base-class)

But better don't fight it, embrace it.